# Qual sinal usar para disparar métodos apartir de uma thread em pyGtk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

Tenho uma Tree View que preciso popular com dados obtidos numa thread, mas se eu o fizer apartir dela o programa apresenta vários problemas aleatórios e erros. Pesquisando descobri que o ideal é disparar um sinal de dentro da thread para que seja chamada uma função que popule a tree view. Então criei um botão e conectei o sinal 'clicked' a função que poupula a tree view, e dentro da thread eu 'emito' o sinal 'clicked' desse botão. Funcionou perfeitamente, mas me parece uma gambiarra e não estou feliz com isso. Existe uma forma mais apropriada para conseguir o mesmo resultado? Ou existe um sinal que possa ser emitido sem a necessidade de criar um widget como eu fiz?
Segue um resumo funcional do meu código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
import requests
import json
import threading

class App(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.button = Gtk.Button() #botão criado apenas pra usar o sinal 'clicked na thread'
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.populate)

        self.tree_model = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, float)
        treeView = Gtk.TreeView(model = self.tree_model)
        cell = Gtk.CellRendererText() 
        column1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Name', cell, text = 0)
        treeView.append_column(column1)
        column2 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Symbol', cell, text = 1)
        treeView.append_column(column2)
        column3 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Price $', cell, text = 2)
        treeView.append_column(column3)
        scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(hexpand = True)
        scrolled.add(treeView)
        self.set_default_size(500,200)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.add(scrolled)
        self.thread() #Iniciando a thread
        self.show_all()

    def populate(self, widget):
        self.tree_model.append([self.name, self.symbol, self.price])

    def get_data(self):
        coins = ('streamr-datacoin', 'ereal', 'burst')
        for coin in coins:
            response = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{}'.format(coin))
            self.name = json.loads(response.text)[0]['name']
            self.symbol = json.loads(response.text)[0]['symbol']
            self.price = float(json.loads(response.text)[0]['price_usd'])
            self.button.emit('clicked') #emitindo sinal para chamar a função populate

    def thread(self):
        self.th1 = threading.Thread(target=self.get_data)
        self.th1.start()

App()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é chamar as funções `GObject.idle_add` ou `GObject.timeout_add` a partir da outra thread. Desta forma a função será chamada diretamente pelo GTK, sem depender do processamento dos sinais. (Documentação aqui: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html)

Apenas isso faria o seu programa funcionar minimamente, mas fiz algumas outras melhorias - coisas como passar os dados da thrad em atributos da classe que podem ser sobreescritos são erradas no sentido de serem propensas a uma rece condition. E também, esse programa só faz sentido se você continuar atualizando as quotações. Como cada chamada demora, fiz de forma que a cada chamada a API, a quotação seja atualizada, e não só quando tiver o valor de todas as moedas.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from itertools import cycle
import threading
import time
import sys

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GObject
import requests

class App(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tree_model = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, float)
        treeView = Gtk.TreeView(model = self.tree_model)
        cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column1 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Name', cell, text = 0)
        treeView.append_column(column1)
        column2 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Symbol', cell, text = 1)
        treeView.append_column(column2)
        column3 = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Price $', cell, text = 2)
        treeView.append_column(column3)
        treeView.hexpand=True
        scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(hexpand = True)
        scrolled.add(treeView)
        self.set_default_size(500,200)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        self.add(scrolled)
        self.input_data = list()
        self.data = dict()
        self.coins = cycle(('streamr-datacoin', 'ereal', 'burst'))
        # GObject.timeout_add(50, self.get_data)
        # GObject.idle_add(self.populate)
        self.thread()
        self.show_all()

    def populate(self, *args):
        if self.input_data:
            data = self.input_data.pop(0)
            name = data["name"]
            if name not in self.data:
                self.data[name] = {"position": len(self.data),  "symbol": data["symbol"], "price": data["price"]}
                self.tree_model.append([name, data["symbol"], data["price"]])
            else:
                self.data[name]["symbol"] = data["symbol"]
                self.data[name]["price"] = data["price"]
                self.tree_model[self.data[name]["position"]] = ([name, data["symbol"], data["price"]])


    def get_data(self):
        while True:
            coin = next(self.coins)
            data = {}
            try:
                url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{}'.format(coin)
                response = requests.get(url)
            except Exception as error:
                print("Error on request to ", url, file=sys.stderr)
            response_data = response.json()
            print(response_data)
            if not isinstance(response_data, list):
                print("Error on request to {}. response: {} ".format(url, response_data), file=sys.stderr)
            else:
                for field in "name symbol price_usd".split():
                    if response_data:
                        data[field] = response_data[0].get(field, "-")
                data["price"] = float(data.pop("price_usd"))
                self.input_data.append(data)
            GObject.idle_add(self.populate)
            # Next coin fetch every 2 seconds
            time.sleep(2)

    def thread(self):
        self.th1 = threading.Thread(target=self.get_data)
        self.th1.start()

App()
Gtk.main()
```

Da forma como está esse código, você pode criar mais chamadas paralelas à API simplesmente criando mais threads com o `self.thread` como alvo.

O truque é usar o itertools.cycle, que devolve o próximo item de uma lista com "next", e retorna ao início. Também é fácil ver que organizei os dados já recuperados em uma estrutura de dados interna, que permite  a atualização dos valores, e inseri um tratamento de erro mínimo nas chamadas à API.

O requests do Python também já pode devolver o conteúdo em json decodificado (e sobretudo, no seu código anterior, você não precisaria chamar o `json.loads` mais de uma vez)

Happy Trading!

Comment: Simplesmente uma aula! Só fiquei com uma dúvida, não seria ideal encerrar a thread  antes de encerrar o Gtk.main()? Na minha aplicação eu sobreescrevi o método do_delete_event, paras mudar uma variável dentro do while para false e encerrar o loop.

Comment: Sim - fazer algo assim para encerrar a thread ficou faltando aí.